# How to download all bucket files using gsutil with django-gae app

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I want to download all bucket files using gsutil in my django non-rel gae app.

Answer (score 1):

gsutil -m cp -R gs://"BUCKET NAME" .

Replace "BUCKET NAME" with the name of your bucket(no quotes) and don't forget the period at the end. If you want to specify a folder replace the period with the destination folder.

-m to perform a parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) copy
-R to copy an entire directory tree

More details can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

Comment: If it has access to qsutil is should.